# How can I pass the `Graphql` mutation query in cypress req and get the data back in response?

Tags: api, graphql, cypress

How can I pass the `Graphql` mutation query in cypress req and get the data back in the response ?
I am getting an error like Validation error of type FieldUndefined: Field 'mutation' in type Query undefined @CreateOrganizationTeam '

```
let author = 'Main Author';
let teamname = 'Green Team';
let query = `mutation CreateOrganizationTeam($input: {category: "", author:${author}, isActive: false, orgId: 10, teamName: ${teamname}}) {
  createOrganizationTeam(input: $input) {
    author
    isActive
    teamName
  }
}`;



/* Cypress test to verify the GraphQl response data  */
Then('I access the graphQL end point', () => {
  cy.request({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'https://some-end-point/api',
    headers: {
      'content-type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      query,
      variables: {
        input: {
          author,
          isActive,
          teamName,
        }
      }
    })
  }).then((response)=>{
    console.log("GraphQL resp output:"+response.body.data);
  });
});
```

Comment: Did the quotes fix it, or do you have another problem that needs sorting?

Comment: Not yet, Now I am getting error `Unable to parse the graphQL query, errorType MalFormattedHtttpRequestException`

Answer (score 2):

Another way of doing it is create the field specifier separately, that way you can see exactly why you need to quote the string values.

```js
const fields = {
  category: "", 
  author: "Main Author", 
  isActive: false, 
  orgId: 10, 
  teamName: "Green Team"
}

let query = `mutation CreateOrganizationTeam($input: ${JSON.stringify(fields)) {...
```

Comment: This is a good alternative which will prevent typos.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to quote the templated variables,

```js
let query = `mutation CreateOrganizationTeam($input: {  
  category: "",   
  author:"${author}",       // quotes around the templated string
  isActive: false,   
  orgId: 10,   
  teamName: "${teamname}"   // quotes around the templated string
}) {
```

In the response you may need `.json()`

```js
.then(r => r.json())
.then(data => {
  console.log("GraphQL resp output:", data);
})
```

Comment: Thank you, so this part is not required ? ```createOrganizationTeam(input: $input) {
    author
    isActive
    teamName
  }```  ?

Comment: Why is it not required?

Comment: Sorry that was my question .!  as your answer doesn't have that part ...so I thought to double check with you...

Comment: I think he's saying that you need to add quotes around `author` and `teamName` in the template literal.

Comment: @Jumaane, Thank you I understood that.

Comment: So, it's a step forward but not removing your error?

Comment: You might find you need to [use the application client](https://glebbahmutov.com/blog/request-graphql/#use-application-client)

Comment: Now I am getting ```Unable to parse the graphQL query, errorType MalFormattedHtttpRequestException```

Comment: In this case will the application client help ?

Comment: **MalFormattedHtttpRequestException**  - You have probably just missed some character from the code. I can help if I can reach the endpoint, otherwise please recheck carefully.